# Unable to change owner of MySite for user profile

Tags: sync, mysite

We are using SharePoint 2010, and it is pulling accounts from 2 domains via Claims Based Auth. The old domain, should be pretty empty of accounts. This is also a single farm setup.

My ULS logs are full with the following entries after I did a Full User Sync. I did this to test pushing values from MySite Users to AD Users (Eg. manager, Phone etc) which I seem to be having issues with after user migrations a while back.

> MySiteCleanup: Unable to change owner of MySite for user profile
>   (domain\PamA).  Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The
>   specified user domain\tillsd could not be found.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureUser(String logonName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MySiteProfileHandler.SetMySiteOwner(UserProfile
>   profile, String newOwner)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MySiteProfileHandler.PreProfileDeleted(UserProfile
>   profile)

Now I believe that the user PamA had tillsd as their manager within MySite, as that is the reporting structure within the company.

Within the Manage User Properties in Central Admin Manager is set as a Person Property Type mapped to Attribute Manager with a Direction of Export.

I do have the Property Mapping For Synchronization set to export to both Domains in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog states that the mysite clean up timer job doesn't run correctly with claims-based auth and provides a manual way to do the cleanup:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx